# Course project for Operating System

Tags: c#, operating-system

I am looking for projects for operating system course. The desire language is C#. There are open source operating system in C# like Singularity, TinyOS etc. But I am bit confused to select which one and what should I target.

I have done lot of google on this but yet no tentative success.

Comment: To fully understand the workings of an operating system and some of the challenges in designing such a project, I think it's important to understand it at a very low level for which you would benefit from learning C and an accompanying assembly language. 
Sorry that doesn't help with your desire to use C#. I'd recommend taking a look at a very early revision of the linux kernel to get an idea of some of the challenges involved.

Comment: What specifically are you looking for in your toy OS? Easy driver development? Easy CPU/Disk/Network scheduler replacement? Memory paging? Why not MINIX or Linux or *BSD? (I have trouble seeing a C# OS kernel, maybe that's neat enough in itself to warrant taking a look :)

Comment: You should have a look as Cosmos too.

Comment: Ah! the crux is C#. I have looked into Cosmos, TinyOS, Singularity, and SharpOS. Personally, I feel why only C. Why not Java? Why not other languages. There must be languages before C. We left them at certain point. Anyhow,it does not mean that C is no more important. But, due to current market needs, we designed curriculum around modern languages and guys are not much aware about C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you are trying to teach you might not need to work with a 'real' OS.

For example, let's say you are trying to teach file-system design.  You could define an interface between the 'OS' and the file-system.  Real operating systems work this way, which is why Linux supports hundreds of file-systems.  Then you could have the students write a file-system driver.  This would let them experience writing file-system support without having to fiddle with a real OS.  It would even make testing simple.  You could test it with unit tests that you define, but don't provide, and see if it passes the test.

Answer (score 0):

> There are open source operating system in C# like Singularity, TinyOS etc

Oh really?

- [TinyOS is written in nesC](http://docs.tinyos.net/index.php/FAQ)
- Singularity is an operating system for hosting C# applications.  The low-level functions (OS services) of Singularity itself are written in [assembler](http://singularity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/45126#324077), [C](http://singularity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/45126#324084), and [C++](http://singularity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/45126#325453).

Answer (score 0):

When I took a operating system / concurrent programming course at university we used [Nachos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_Another_Completely_Heuristic_Operating_System) for laboration. It is built with the intention for teaching, yet it was at the time the largets code base most of us had met. Dealing with a real operating system kernel would be overwhelming for most normal courses.

According to the Wikipedia page there are successors that are more modern / up to date than Nachos. Those are probably interesting to look into.